# Google Style Version Info Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml

I am looking to imitate the version info dialog found in most (if not all) Google apps. These dialogs are usually found in 'Help & Feedback' > 'Options Menu' > 'Version Info'. For example this is the dialog found in the Photos app:

[image]

I am having trouble centering the title and version number text relative to the icon, while aligning the copyright text to the left edge of the title and version. I know I could center the two `TextView` elements by doing something like this:

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding" android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/title_layout" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/icon" android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/title"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

But then how would I add the copyright `TextView` without messing up the centering? I tried using a `CoordinatorLayout` as well, but I could not seem to get the two `TextView` elements to align to the right of the icon while remaining centered. I also want to add a `ListView` (or `RecyclerView`) to the dialog, below the copyright text, but that should not be too difficult after I figure this out.

The only thing I can think of is to wrap the whole thing in another layout, add a `TextView` to that layout, and give it a left margin equal to the width of the `ImageView` (including its margins). But I feel like I should be able to do this without having to add Java code, or hardcoding a dimension equal to the width of the `ImageView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to use TableLayout, so the code will be something like this:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TableRow>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/title_layout" 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="16dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="first line"/>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/another"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="second line"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Space />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="thirdline"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

This is how it looks on my phone
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Ah, this works perfectly! Honestly, I had forgotten about the `TableLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want(I do this by `RelativeLayout`):

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/example_image" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="title"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="description"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/some_txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/layout"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/layout"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:text="some thing else"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Comment: This works great as well, I had not thought of nesting another `RelativeLayout` inside of the title text layout. I had tried to apply the `android:layout_centerVertical` attribute to the outer layout, but I was confused as to why it wouldn't actually center the `TextView` elements inside. The only reason I went with the answer by @НикитаХлебушкин is because I think the code itself looks *slightly* cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout and set the textviews to align to the right of the ImageView (android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon")